# Dropdown not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on my rails app. I have a settings dropdown which works on local host but doesnt work on heroku. Please help me fix this issue. I tried all possible solutions i could find but still not working. I even tried making changes on environment file as well by nothing worked for me.

production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

_navigation.html.erb

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to "Change password", changepassword_path %></li>
        <% if current_user.superadmin? %>
          <li><a href="/main-admin/manage-users">Manage Users</a></li>
           <li><a href="/main-admin/general-settings">General Settings</a> 
           </li> 
          <% end %>            
     </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Freetoplay</title>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= csp_meta_tag %>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    </head>
    <body>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
        <div class="bd">      
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                  <%= render_breadcrumbs :separator => " / " %>
                </ol>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
          <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </body>
  </html>
```

gem file

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.5.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem "paperclip", "~> 6.0.0"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"
gem "wysiwyg-rails"
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'filterrific'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'

  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but I always run these commands to update my css for Heroku.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: this is the error I get when I write the above command -missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`

Comment: Ah, okay. Are you using Devise? And do you have a .env or a secrets.yaml file to store your secret keys in? Or maybe Figaro gem?

Comment: no i m not using devise. nor I have any secrets.yaml file. I used heroku config command on my terminal to look for secret_key_base and yes I have the key.

Comment: This might help you with your secret key base issue. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556955/heroku-config-secret-key-base-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556955/heroku-config-secret-key-base-error)