# RAILS APP : heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to launch my rails app from my local computer to HEROKU. I've searched on stackoverflow but I can't seem to find information about this issue - Some say it's a profile and others say it's a package.json file. None of it actually worked - is there something I'm missing?

**Gem File**

```
group :development do 
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

**Heroku Logs --Tail**

```
2019-05-14T07:31:46.981736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-14T07:31:50.681385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 18879 -e production`
2019-05-14T07:31:55.137458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-14T07:31:55.106359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019384+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:33:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019424+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019426+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019428+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019438+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019440+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019446+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019448+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019450+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019451+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019453+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019458+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019460+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019467+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019469+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019470+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019472+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019473+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019475+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `server'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019477+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:105:in `use_puma?'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019482+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `print_boot_information'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019484+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:47:in `start'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019486+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019487+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019489+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019490+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019492+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019494+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019495+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019500+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019502+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019504+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019505+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019507+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019508+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019510+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019512+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019513+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019515+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.019522+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2019-05-14T07:31:55.022993+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-05-14T07:31:56.410195+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=warm-harbor-88564.herokuapp.com request_id=5926f399-ce9e-4671-b545-de0eb7dca827 fwd="66.229.63.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-14T07:31:57.780810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-harbor-88564.herokuapp.com request_id=7b9663f4-abe7-4281-a41d-f867dc8e5aad fwd="66.229.63.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: try lauching your app in production mode on your compute `rails c production` to get more information about why your app cannot boot

Comment: `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)` indicates that you are trying to load the `thin` gem in your application but that is is not in your `Gemfile` anymore. Did you try to add `gem "thin"` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` again?

Comment: @VincentRolea this is the error I get:

rails c production
/Users/donwydens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:585:in `validate_secret_key_base': Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)

Comment: @spickermann I just added the gem to my Gemfile and it loaded! What exactly is the Thing Gem? Ruby Gem website does not have a home page - links to a dead link... thanks again

Comment: Thanks for reporting the error. This is pretty self explanatory, it looks like you don't have any rails secret key base, try having a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556955/heroku-config-secret-key-base-error

Comment: @ManuelQuintanilla `thin` is a webserver like `puma` many others. I wrote a proper answer because my comment seems to have solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
```

indicates that you are trying to load the [`thin` gem](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/) in your application but that is is not in your referenced in you `Gemfile` – Perhaps you installed it manually in your development machine or the code that raises the error runs only on the production environment.

Just add the `thin` gem to you `Gemfile`

```
gem 'thin'
```

run `bundle install` again and redeploy the changes to Heroku.